# Checkbox to control radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have a `checkbox` and 3 `radio buttons`, I'm trying to have one of the `radio buttons` selected if the checkbox is checked and have any of them un-selected if the `checkbox` is unchecked.

My solution works on the first run, but wont select the radio button after the first click.

```
$('#checkbox-h-2g').click(function () {
    if ($('#checkbox-h-2g').is(":checked")) {
        $('#r1').attr('checked', true);
    }if (!$('#checkbox-h-2g').is(":checked")) {
        $('#r1 , #r2, #r3').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: In your second `if` you should use each to loop through each radio and make it un-checked. Same should go for checked variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set properties, Also your code can be improved as

```
$('#checkbox-h-2g').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#r1').prop('checked', true);
    }else{
        $('#r1 , #r2, #r3').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Also better to use change event since you can use keyboard to check the checkbox.

Comment: You can normally use the keyboard to click too (space bar) the change event only triggers on blur

Comment: @jcubic, Many browsers invoke `click` handler when state of `check-box` is changed.. [Ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35)